# C2061 - Circular dependency

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, circular-reference

How to avoid circular dependency on these code:

Mechanic.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Characters.h"
#include "Monsters.h"

using namespace characters;
using namespace monsters;
using namespace std;

void character::character_atack(character const cha, monster &monst)
{
    if (cha.dexterity + k(20) >= monst.defense)
        monst.health = monst.health - cha.strength;
}
int k(int const max)
{
    return (rand() % max);
}
void monster::monster_atack(character &cha, monster const monst)
{
    if (monst.atack + k(20) >= cha.dexterity)
        cha.health = cha.health - monst.damage;
}
```

Monsters.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace monsters
{
    using namespace std;

    class monster{
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        int atack;
        int damage;
        int health;
        int defense;

        monster(int atk, int dmg, int hp, int def) : atack(atk), damage(dmg),
                health(hp), defense(def) {}
        ~monster();

        void monster_atack(character &cha, monster const monst);
    };

    class greenskins:monster{
        greenskins(int atk, int dmg, int hp, int def) : monster(atk, dmg, hp, def) {}
    };
}
```

Characters.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace characters
{
    using namespace std;

    class character{
    protected:
        int level;
        int experience;
        string name;
    public:
        int health;
        int strength;
        int intelligence;
        int dexterity;

        struct position{
            int x;
            int y;
        }pos;

        character(int str, int in, int dex) : strength(str), intelligence(in),
                dexterity(dex), level(1), experience(0) { 
            cout << "What's your name?" << endl;
            cin >> name; }
        ~character();

        void info_character();
        void character_atack(character const cha, monster &monst);
    };
}
```

The compilator gives me errors like this:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'monster'
```

or

```
Error   9   error C2511: 'void monsters::monster::monster_atack(characters::character &,const monsters::monster)' : overloaded member function not found in 'monsters::monster'
```

Comment: That is not a circular dependency.

Comment: @Kulis: This seems to be compiler error. Can you post full source code.

Comment: Pass character to character_attack by const reference to avoid copying the whole object each time.

Comment: character_attack also has access to the current object. Why pass another character?

Comment: monsters.h and characters.h should include each other or forward declare the other class.

Comment: It seems more like both classes should inherit some common interface "entity" that you can pass to either method, and then not only does the circular dependency go away but monsters could damage other monsters if you wanted.

Comment: What about the class character used in the monster::monster_atack declaration? It is not in the character namespace...could it be characters::character? ( eg. void monster_atack(characters::character &cha, monster const monst); )

Comment: As suggestion, please split the mechanics.cpp in 2 files one for each header/class. In that way every cpp ( one for character and one for monster ) will use less "using namespace" directives.

Comment: @NeilKirk Can you desribe more precisely your first question?

Comment: @cdhowie You suggest to create "mother" of these two class?

Comment: @StefanoBuora I have less namespace, but more files. This approach is optimal?

Comment: How do you call character_atack?

Comment: @Kulis I would, yes. They could share some information in the base class, such as HP and possibly some other stats as well. Then the `character` and `monster` classes can focus only on the things that make them different from each other.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `character` has a function that takes a `monster&` and `monster` has a function that takes a `character&`, but you don't declare the other class in either case. Thankfully, since you just pass the classes as arguments in both places (as opposed to having them be members or something), it is sufficient to forward-declare both classes in both places:

```
// in character.h
namespace monsters {
    class monster; // just fwd-declare
}

namespace characters {
    class character {
        // as before
    };
}
```

And similar in the other file.

[update] Also, you're just referencing `monster` inside of `class character` in the header file, you need to qualify it as `monsters::monster`.

Comment: @Kulis You show the errors but not the line of code so that is no help to anyone.

Comment: https://imgur.com/SyNrqbA (35) void character_atack(const character& cha, monster& monst);
    (24) void monster_atack(character& cha, const monster& monst);
    (69) void character::character_atack( const character& cha, monster& monst)
    (75) void monster::monster_atack(character& cha, const monster& monst)

Comment: I can't see any of those images, so I don't know what you problem is - but I'm guessing my [update] might fix it.

Comment: After this change, I have only: Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall characters::character::~character(void)" (??1character@characters@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain

Comment: You declare `~character()` but don't define it anywhere.

Comment: I also declare ~monster() in class monster, but this don't cause a problem. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The first error comes from the following line in **Characters.h**

```
void character_atack(character const cha, monster &monst);
```

You include **Characters.h** into your .cpp file before you include the **Monsters.h** and thus the type **monster** is not yet known. To fix this, change your **Characters.h** to look like this:

```
... //includes
namespace monsters {
  class monster;
}

namespace characters {
   class character {
        ... //class definition   
   }
}
```

---

The second error is a not matching signature. You are declaring following method:

```
 void monster_atack(character &cha, monster const monst)
```

but defining

```
 void monster::monster_atack(character &cha, const monster monst)
```

At least that is what the compiler said.

I would suggest to change the signature to:

```
void monster_atack(character &cha, const monster& monst)
```

to prevent needless copy operations. (depending on optimization of course)